# How to draw and process some 3D points?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, graphics, 3d, drawing

I have some points like

```
1,2,3
1,1,1
2,3,4
2,5,6
9,10,2
66,43,23
```

I want to draw and see them in the page but I don't know how can I do this. I read a little about XNA but I think there is better way. Can you help me?

**update**

I want to simulate 3D points as 3DMax does. it means have a 3d shape and can look it in all degrees.

Comment: This cannot be answered properly without a good deal more information. How do you want to display the points? As a set of vertices?
As a set of triangles? It really needs a hell of a lot more elaboration....

Comment: well, at first I just want to have some points in space. after that I might want to draw some lines using the points.

Comment: I'm just trying to help and did not mean to answer it incorrectly, I apologise, yes, it should have been a comment, for heavens sake.

Comment: Yes, you need to further explain what your end goal is.  XNA is a good choice if you will be animating.  If not, you might be able to get by using paint events in a panel

Comment: Well you have a few options.  If you just want to visualize a point cloud, then [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) may be the way to go. That said, this wouldn't be a programming question if using other existing software would do.

Comment: @bobobobo thanks. It is a programming question because I don't know any application and I want to know is there a good way to simulate points in the screen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a 3d graphics drawing API.

There are 2 main ones:

- OpenGL
- Direct3D

OpenGL is cross platform and is used on mobile devices like Android and iPhone.

Direct3D is Microsoft specific and generally is for Windows platform only.

Don't *overestimate* the value of building a cross-platform app.  If it's a small pet project and you're not planning to go cross platform in the future, *don't choose a more difficult API just because it's cross platform*.

[Programming OpenGL quite easy to start with via GLUT from C++](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/getting-started-with-glut/), and [there are tons of simple examples on the web](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/tutors.html)

You can also use Direct3D via XNA, which is also easy to start with.  There are a huge number of XNA 4.0 tutorials [on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_QqcFimkkg) (I haven't watched it, it just has a very green likes bar!)  and also the [msdn tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203894.aspx)